# Yosemite Detects Faulty RAM Module But Apple Hardware Test Does Not?

Tags: macos, memory, mac-pro

I just bought a used MacPro3,1 on Amazon.  The system came with Mac OS X 10.6 but I downloaded Yosemite and it states that one of the 2GB modules is faulty.

[image: Faulty 2 GB Module as listed in About this Mac]

When I installed Yosemite it wiped out diagnostics for Apple Hardware Test (AHT) but this isn't a big deal as it can be downloaded and [booted from USB for particular Mac models](http://rivenbyfive.blogspot.com/2012/01/download-and-run-apple-hardware-test.html).  When I ran the AHT in extended testing mode (a test that runs for two hours) it states that I don't have any issues:

[image: AHT with "no trouble found" displayed and "Pass Number 1, Total Time Testing: 2 Hours 3 Mins 18 Secs"]

[image: Module listed as having EEC Errors]

## **Update**

The new RAM came in, and I put it in in place of the bad RAM, and the same spot is still showing the EEC errors.  The replacement RAM I was sent had a different number on it then the rest of the RAM, but I'm starting to think it isn't the RAM, it's maybe the Reiser.  Can anyone confirm this?  Can this damage the RAM?  However sometimes, it boots and doesn't have an issue with the RAM.  I'm starting to think it has something to do with sleep mode.

[image: Modules with Full RAM and same slot complaining about EEC Errors]

[image: EEC Errors]

## Update 2

Okay so it's definitely the Riser.  I swapped Risers, and waited a little bit and now it's reporting it on the other Riser.

[image: Switched out Riser now it's on the other side]

Comment: Using the About This Mac, can you check if all RAM's are the same model?

Comment: I don't know...I could open it up to find out though, I guess.  They have to have the same kind in Bank A, Bank B as such though right?

Comment: Actually before using a screwdriver, open about this Mac more ect.. then click on memory and compare the info for each one listed there.

Comment: It says something about `ECC Errors`: http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27175?viewlocale=en_US seems to mean something about impending DIMM failure.  What causes this?  Age?

Comment: It looks like it might be a paired unit. Try populating the A3 and B3 slots.

Comment: Raiser A was completely populated with 2GB modules, in Raiser B, DIMM1 and DIMM2 were populated with 2GB modules.  In Raiser B, I moved the DIMM2 module to DIMM3 and restarted; now I have 8 GBs of RAM instead of 12 GBs.  I don't think that was the issue.

Comment: I got new RAM in and replaced it from the guy I bought it from, I'll double check when I get home but I think the issue is on the board as the new RAM is giving me the same error.